# Continuous connection errors with Android Wear emulator

Tags: java, android, connection, emulation, logcat

I recently set up an Android Wear emulator, installed a few apps to it, and now my logcat is being bombarded with continuous, infinitely repeating connection errors:

```
03-16 11:19:32.534 1624-2115/? I/WearableConn: Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601

03-16 11:19:32.536 1624-2115/? W/WearableConn: Error writing to device, error: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

03-16 11:19:32.536 1624-2115/? I/WearableConn: Socket closed

03-16 11:19:32.537 1624-2115/? I/WearableConn: Waiting 4.0 seconds to retry connection
```

I'm using Marshmallow (API 23), x86, Android 6.0